# Are classes necessary in Javascript? What effect do they have on creating objects?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, javascript-objects

Consider this example code:

```
class Test {
    say() {
        console.log("I'm a test.");
    }
}

let TestFromClass = new Test();

let TestFromObject = {
    say() {
        console.log("I'm also a test.");
    }
};


TestFromClass.say();    // Output: I'm a test.
TestFromObject.say();   // Output: I'm also a test.
```

I understand that it's possible to create objects, such as `TestFromObject`, without first creating a class with the `class` keyword. Is `class` necessary at all? Is there a difference between these two kinds of objects? If so, what effect does it have to use `class` explicitly?

Comment: just syntactic sugar

Comment: It's not so much about the difference between them but which one should be be used in what situation. Using a class is useful if you're going to create a bunch of instances. The seconds one, the object literal, is basically a Singleton, useful to group stuff together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `new` creates a new object whose internal prototype is the class's prototype. For example:

```js
class Test {
    say() {
        console.log("I'm a test.");
    }
}

let TestFromClass = new Test();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(TestFromClass) === Test.prototype);
```

This is useful for creating multiple objects. The usual reason to do this is so that each object can have some sort of associated *state* - generally, the values of its properties. For example, a `Person` object might have a `name` and an `age` property.

However, if there is no data to associate with an instance (as with `TestFromClass` in the original code), there's not much point having an instance at all. The `TestFromObject` approach makes much more sense if the purpose is just to collect named functions into a data structure.

That said, it's sometimes desirable to have a class that has some functions associated with it (like `say`) which don't have anything to do with an instance of its data, *while still* being able to create an instance - perhaps using other methods on the prototype. This isn't that uncommon, and is done by making the non-instance-related functions `static`:

```js
class Person {
  static canEat() {
    return ['apples', 'bananas', 'carrots'];
  }
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
const p = new Person('Bob', 99);
console.log(p.name);
console.log(Person.canEat());
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer! Do you know how to write the UML of `TestFromObject`? Since it has no inheritance?

Comment: @Dop4miN - `TestFromObject` **does** have inheritance. It inherits from `Object.prototype`, as I describe in my answer. The only way to create an object that *doesn't* have inheritance is `var thisHasNoPrototype = Object.create(null);`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - to be honest, I didn't quite understand your answer before, sorry.

Comment: @Dop4miN - :-) No worries, I may have inferred that you knew more about JS than you do (or I could be wrong). The various questions and answers listed in [this search](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+prototypical+inheritance) may help. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - You were right, I'm actually pretty new to OOP in general. Thanks for the list! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a difference between these two kinds of objects? If so, what effect does it have to use class explicitly?

There effectively isn't a meaningful difference, but it does have some minor effects:

- When you create an object with literal syntax, unless you use the special `__proto__` property name, its prototype will always be `Object.prototype`. (Note that `__proto__` is [officially *optional*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__), a JavaScript engine doesn't have to provide it.) When you create it with `new X`, provided `X` is a constructor function created with `class` syntax, the result will have the prototype `X.prototype`.
- Methods defined within an object literal are directly placed on the object. Methods within `class X` go on `X.prototype` (non-`static` ones) which the object *inherits*.

Comment: Okay, I've read a bit about prototypes in JavaScript. So is there any difference in the usage of methods when it's inside the `__proto__`property instead of inside the object itself?

Comment: @Dop4miN Just to be clear: You mean when they're in the prototype, rather than in the object itself. (You're best off pretending the `__proto__`  property doesn't exist. Just think in terms of the prototype of the object.) There isn't any real difference in usage most of the time. Of course, the ones on the prototype are shared with other instances, but that doesn't usually make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

A class is more or less just syntactic sugar for a prototype:

```
// The class way
class Test {
  say() {
    console.log("I'm a test.");
  }
}


// The old fashioned way
function Test() {

}

Test.prototype.say = function () {
  console.log("I'm a test.");
};
```

The difference in both these cases with direct object creation is that the methods belong to the prototype, not directly to the object.

The code `TestFromClass.say()` must go through the prototype chain to find a `say` method, while TestFromObject directly has the method.

Other than that, there's no difference.

Comment: Is the `TestFromObject.say()` faster then?

Comment: I've done a small test and it looks like so. You should probably ignore that fact, though. It should'n really matter. On the other hand, if you instanciate thousands of object, the prototype way will be more memory efficient as there is only function say instead of a thousand

Comment: That's true. Thanks for testing and your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Objects come in two forms: the declarative (literal) form, and the constructed form.

The literal syntax for an object looks like this:

```js
var myObj = {
    key: value
    // ...
};
```

The constructed form looks like this:

```js
var myObj = new Object();
myObj.key = value;
```

The constructed form and the literal form result in exactly the same sort of object. The only difference really is that you can add one or more key/value pairs to the literal declaration, whereas with constructed-form objects, you must add the properties one-by-one.

Note: It's extremely uncommon to use the "constructed form" for creating objects as just shown. You would pretty much always want to use the literal syntax form. The same will be true of most of the built-in objects.

**P.S.** To read more in detail go to 
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/this-object-prototypes/ch3.md

Answer (score 0):

So you created a class called `Test` which is the base class. The you added a method called `say() {}`.

```
class Test {
    say() {
        console.log("I'm a test.");
    }
}
```

Then you created an instance of the `Test` class below:

```
let TestFromClass = new Test();
```

And below that you created a plain JavaScript object called `TestFromObject`:

```
let TestFromObject = {
    say() {
        console.log("I'm also a test.");
    }
};
```

And yes, they will both print out the output you have to their methods:

```
TestFromClass.say();    // Output: I'm a test.
TestFromObject.say();   // Output: I'm also a test.
```

The difference will not begin until you utilize the full power of the class you created, for example, utilizing the `cconstructor()` function like so:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {

    }
    say() {
        console.log("I'm a test.");
    }
}
```

Now the constructor function is automatically called for us when we use the `new` keyword for the class name. With a constructor function you know also have access to `this` like so:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
      this.type = 'test';
    }
    say() {
        console.log("I'm a test.");
    }
}
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
TestFromClass.say();    // Output: I'm a test.
TestFromObject.say();   // Output: I'm also a test.
TestFromClass.type;     // Output: test
```

The constructor is traditionally used to do some initial setup inside the class or particular instance of the class.

The constructor is commonly used by using some arguments when creating a new instance of the class. Maybe you want to specify that the class of Test you have created has 50 questions. You can pass in an object to the new Test instance like so:

```
let TestFromClass = new Test({ questions: 50 });
```

You can call this object whatever you want, let's just call the object `examination` and you can set the number of questions to this `examination` object.

So now you pass that object into the constructor function and calling that object, `examination` like so:

```
class Test {
    constructor(examination) {
      this.questions = examination.questions;
      this.type = 'test';
    }
    say() {
        console.log("I'm a test.");
    }
}

let TestFromClass = new Test({ questions: 50 });

TestFromClass.say();    // Output: I'm a test.
TestFromClass.type;     // Output: test
TestFromClass.questions; // 50
```

The other thing you can do with a class object is create a subclass that would extend the functionality of your base class and then you can also add some customized functionality to it.

```
class Test {
    constructor(examination) {
      this.questions = examination.questions;
      this.type = 'test';
    }
    say() {
        console.log("I'm a test.");
    }
}

class Quiz extends Test {

}
```

So now your Quiz is inheriting all the methods, functions, properties, etcetera that are in the Test class and define additional methods inside of it.

```
class Test {
    constructor(examination) {
      this.questions = examination.questions;
      this.type = 'test';
    }
    say() {
        console.log("I'm a test.");
    }
}

class Quiz extends Test {
    constructor(examination) {
    this.topic = examination.topic;
  }
}
```

So now to ensure that the constructor function from the parent class is called as well, I can use the `super()` keyword into the constructor:

```
class Test {
    constructor(examination) {
      this.questions = examination.questions;
      this.type = 'test';
    }
    say() {
        console.log("I'm a test.");
    }
}

class Quiz extends Test {
    constructor(examination) {
    super(examination)
    this.topic = examination.topic;
  }
}
```

Then you can instantiate that subclass like so:

```
const javascript = new Quiz({topic: 'javascript', questions: 50 });
```

and finally print it out:

```
javascript.questions; // Output: 50
```